# How to pass props from one page to another in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-props

Solved version of the question, the code lines are correct, with the console log I checked all parameters are being passed correctly:

I'm doing a website where I want to display my personal projects, all of this with components between pages. The main content is displayed in the work page that has this component:

```
<WorkText name={"personal1"} text={"some text goes here"} url={"./public/img1.jpg"}/>
```

I just want to add this line everytime I want to show a new project, and make it dynamic.

The component comes from here:

```
import React from "react";
import "./WorkText.scss";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

const WorkText = ({name, text, url}) => {

   const Data = {
      name,
      text,
      url
    }

  return (
    <p className="work-text-parent">
      <a className="bar">{type}/</a><Link to={{ pathname: "/work/" + name}} state={Data}>{name}</Link>
    </p>
  );
};

export default WorkText;
```

and want to import it to a page that has this structure:

```
import React from "react";
import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom";
import "./WorkDetail.scss";

const WorkDetail = () => {
  
  const location = useLocation();
  const { type, name, text, url } = location.state;
  console.log(location.state);

  return (
      <div className="work-parent2">
        <h2>{name}</h2>
        <img src={url} alt={name} />
        <p>{text}</p>
      </div>
  );
}

export default WorkDetail;
```

I am currently using useParams but I only get the link of the page under the name of workname, that's how I call it in the App.js:

```
<Route exact path="/work/:workname" element={<><NavbarExtended /><WorkDetail /><Footer /></>}/>
```

I can't get to make the props work and don't know if using the useLocation, useHistory... I'am a bit lost and would like to passa the props to the work detail page.

You can see how it works in this link going to the page of WORK
https://marclopez.oddsolutionslab.com/

Comment: you can click the checkmark on answers to accept a solution. don't edit the question and write "solved" in the title.

Comment: I know, but the answer wasn't the solution at all, there were some modifications needed to make it work, what would you do for others to see the right code?

Comment: you can post an answer to your own question. that is encouraged if you find/derive the answer on your own.

Answer (score 1):

To pass props from one page to another in React, you can use the `Link` component provided by React Router. You can pass props as an object in the `to` prop of the `Link` component, and then access those props in the receiving component using the `useLocation` hook provided by React Router.

you can modify your `WorkText` component to pass props to the `WorkDetail` component:

```
import React from "react";
import "./WorkText.scss";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

const WorkText = ({name, text, url}) => {

  return (
    <p>
      <Link to={{ pathname: "/work/" + name, state: { text, url } }}>{name}</Link>
    </p>
  );
};

export default WorkText;
```

Then, in your `WorkDetail` component, you can access these props using the `useLocation` hook like this:

```
import React from "react";
import "./WorkDetail.scss";
import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom";

const WorkDetail = () => {
  
  const location = useLocation();
  const { name } = useParams();
  const { text, url } = location.state;

  return (
      <div className="work-parent2">
        <h2>{name}</h2>
        <img src={url} alt={name} />
        <p>{text}</p>
      </div>
  );
}

export default WorkDetail;
```

Comment: okay, I understand the process but I don't understand why I'm getting this error: **Cannot destructure property 'text' of 'location.state' as it is null**

Comment: This is likely happening because you are not passing any state when navigating to the WorkDetail component.

Comment: To pass state from one component to another using react-router-dom, you can use the Link component to navigate to the WorkDetail component, and pass the state as a second argument to the to prop of the Link.

Comment: I think I am passing props correctly, basically i use the way you said, however it keep saying it is a null, and when console.log the state keeps appearing as a null

Comment: The location.state object is only populated when the page is loaded. If you are trying to access the text property before the page has loaded, you will also get this error.

Comment: okay, I finally got it working, I will update the code in case anyone want to check, thanks Vishnu!!!!

Comment: You're welcome! Glad to hear that you were able to resolve the issue.